# Inline visible vs. User prompted Popup for registration form

Tags: forms, registration

On the homepage of a site we want to show the registration form to sign up.

My boss wants the form to be already visible facebook/twitter style.

I prefer to have it open in a popup when the user clicks the sign up button, mainly because it keeps things clean and minimalist especially on mobile.

Is thereany good evidence as to which works best? If it were a popup would conversion rates drop?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this is a decision that should be made on the type of content you are planning to offer. If the homepage of your website does not need to expose user valuable information and the user will need authentication in order to reach his goal on your website then you should make an easy accessible registration form such as Facebook/Twitter but otherwise you want to save that space for customer pitching and other valuable information that you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the signup should be available when the users already knows what he/she will benefit from signing up. There is no interest in making it very prominent if the user does not know why he/she is signing up. So making it very obvious from the very homepage might not be the best solution... Best to include it on a page where you describe the services that become available when signing up.